# how to copy a function optimally

Tags: c

I have a function that is called by polling (every 10 ms) and it has a check on it's start:

```
if(input != saved_data)
    return;
// rest of the function...
```

and while this check saves a lot of time, sometimes it's wrong, and I'm currently debugging a situation where I need to keep executing the function albeit the `input == saved_data`.

I thought of 2 options:

1. add a "force" flag to the argument list, and while it's true, the if will be disregarded
2. create a new function `old_function_force` with the same code, except the if

I chose option 2 because I didn't want to modify all the other callings to the function, and I wanted the code to be backwards compatible, but it occurred to me that my solution is also bad, because when someone should change the `old_function` he will probably forget to change mine, and that would cause new bugs

Is there a better solution other then these two, or a way to improve one of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A mixture of both is actually how you can avoid code duplication and changing every possible call site:

1. Rename your function and add the flag parameter.

   ```
   void func_with_force(/*parameters*/, bool force)
   {
     if(!force && input != saved_data)
       return;

     // Other code
   }
   ```
2. Add a new function, under the **old** name, that calls the one above with the flag equal to `false`.

   ```
   void func(/*parameters*/)
   {
     func_with_force(/*Argument forwarding*/, false);
   }
   ```

And yes, I assumed `stdbool.h`.

---

You can also go a step further and place `func` completely in a header; just add the inline specifier:

```
inline void func(/*parameters*/)
{
  func_with_force(/*Argument forwarding*/, false);
}
```

To quote the C11 standard (6.7.4p7):

> For a function with external linkage, the following restrictions apply: If a function is declared with an inline function specifier, then it shall also be defined in the same translation unit. If all of the file scope declarations for a function in a translation unit include the inline function specifier without extern, then the definition in that translation unit is an inline definition. An inline definition does not provide an external definition for the function, and does not forbid an external definition in another translation unit.

The above means that even if many translation units include the header, the inline definitions won't interfere with each other. And being so short, it's very likely that the stub will simply be optimized into a direct call to your new function.

Comment: I assume that when I want a forced exec. I will call the func_with_force(/*parameters*/, true), yes?

Comment: @noob - Precisely. I mostly focused on how to add the new functionality with as low a cost as possible. Naturally if you want to use the new ability you'd need to call the newly named function.